# Save copy process/work by use of update in cp

Tags: files, synchronization

How is to update in `cp -u` to really work in saving file save/copy work

just copied to  `/tmp/onram/cpp` and only moddded gainRun.sh

```
$ ls -l
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 80 Oct  7 07:02 /tmp/onram/cpp
total 8
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 116 Oct  7 07:02 gainRun.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 175 Oct  7 07:01 m.c
```

peek the source before copy back by `-u` opt.

```
$ ls -l ~/Downloads/c
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Oct  6 09:28 /home/bot/Downloads/c
total 8
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 108 Oct  6 09:11 gainRun.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 175 Oct  6 09:11 m.c
```

so time to test go copy it

```
$ cp -ru /tmp/onram/cpp/*  ~/Downloads/c

'/tmp/opera-beta/cpp/gainRun.sh' -> '/home/bot/Downloads/c/gainRun.sh'
'/tmp/onram/cpp/m.c' -> '/home/bot/Downloads/c/m.c'
```

just copy indiscriminately all, not only just modded `gainRun.sh`

please help complete correct steps to saving file save/copy work if it wasn't done so

Comment: You may want to get out of the habit of doing such experimentation as the `root` user.

Answer (score 0):

`cp -u` - copies files based on last modification time of the origin file/s.

`cp -ur` - Does the same as above but includes content found in subdirectories.

Image showing before:

[image: Image showing timestamps before modifying files]

And this next image shows the result afterwards (note the time difference for the two files I modified before copying)

[image: Image showing result of cp -u]

Notice that only the modified files' timestamp changes indicating the command works just file.

I hope that helps.